# How to bind a contract to anonymous class definition

Tags: racket

I have a method which returns class definitions:

```
(define (max-tracker%)
  (let ([current-maximum 0])
    (class object%
      (init val) ; <--
      ...
      (define held-value 0)
      (set-val val)
      (define/public (set-val newval) ; <--
        (when (newval . >= . current-maximum)
          (set! current-maximum newval))
        (set! held-value newval))
      ...
      )))
```

how do I bind a contract to the `set-val` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`with-contract`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fregion..rkt%29._with-contract%29%29) form, which lets you create arbitrary contract regions in expressions:

```
(define (max-tracker%)
  (with-contract
    max-tracker-procedure
    #:result contract-expr
    (class object% (init val) ...)))
```

This creates a contract region named `max-tracker-procedure` that exports exactly one anonymous value that must adhere to the contract specified in `contract-expr`. In this case you could specify a [`class/c`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Object_and_Class_Contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fclass..rkt%29._class%2Fc%29%29) contract. Multiple values and exports can be specified too, by using Racket's ability to return multiple values and using `#:results (contract-expr ...)` instead. Here's a simpler example demonstrating this:

```
(define test-value
  (with-contract test
    #:result (or/c integer? symbol?)
    "neither int nor symbol - should break contract"))
```

Running this should give you:

```
broke its contract:
promised: (or/c integer? symbol?)
produced: "neither int nor symbol - should break contract"
in: (or/c integer? symbol?)
contract from: (region test)
blaming: (region test)
```

Combining this with `class/c` should give you what you're looking for.

### EDIT

Here's an example closer to what you'd like:

```
(define (with-greeting class%)
  (with-contract with-greeting
    #:result (class/c [greet (->m string? string?)])
    (class class%
      (super-new)
      (define/public (greet person)
        (string-append "Hello, " person "!")))))

(define simple-greeter% (with-greeting object%))
(define simple-greeter (new simple-greeter%))
(send simple-greeter greet "Jack")
(send simple-greeter greet 'Jack)
```